# How to view txt/pdf flle on Google drive in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am working on an App in which I require to access to files stored on Google drive,which works well.

Now, I am trying to display that selected file on the device, I am using UIWebView for that purpose. I have read the documents from Google, I could not find anything in relation with viewing the file(txt/pdf/spread sheet etc).

Here is my code -- I am firing when user taps on a cell of UITableView:

```
GTLDriveFile *file = [loadedFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        GTMHTTPFetcher * fetcher = [applicationDelegate.serviceDriveGtl.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:file.downloadUrl];
        [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData * data,NSError * error) {

            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR ON LOADING FILE:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            } else {
                  NSString * link = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                    encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];

                    DisplayViewController * displayView = [[DisplayViewController alloc] init];
                    [displayView showDocumentOnLink:link];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:displayView animated:YES];
    }
```

Now, Here is how I am populating it WebView: 
I am collecting the "link" variable in "getLink" in "DisplayViewController".

```
displayWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[displayWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(posX, posY+230, width, 200)];
[displayWebView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:displayWebView];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getLink]];
[displayWebView loadRequest:request];
```

What am I missing here ? Why does the WebView not populate the file contents ?
Any help with truly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: how are you managing active session?

Comment: I am have declared ServiceDrive in AppDelegate files.There only I initiate it and use it throughout the app.

Comment: are you able to download the file?

Comment: Yes.. File can be downloaded.